# Go regexp: how I can replace named groups by concrete values in source pattern?

Tags: regex, go

Maybe, you could help me.

For example, I have regular expression like `(?P<name>\w+) (?P<surname>\w+)`.

How I can using `map[string]string{"name": "Alice", "surname": "Cool"}` replace groups to obtain string `Alice Cool`? And is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found how make it. Hope it's will help someone.

https://play.golang.org/p/Xz9PtE_bIt

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this method does not works with dots and slashes in plaintext.
When I am trying to replace values from a map into a regex with Ip format `(?P<1>\d{1,3}).(?P<2>\d{1,3}).(?P<3>\d{1,3}).(?P<4>\d{1,3})`, I am getting `127(?-s:.)1(?-s:.)0(?-s:.)1` instead of expected `127.1.0.1`.

https://go.dev/play/p/FnJCLkwXGTx.